# Get a list of all JSP errors using Netbeans

Tags: java, html, jsp, netbeans

In Netbeans 6.8, how do I get all the errors in JSPs? I can see no error annotations for Java in-line code. You can see the error only when the JSP is opened. When I try to run my web project, it does not cause any error too, only when the erroneous JSP is opened in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Task List window in NetBeans to show errors](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2008/08/task-list-window-in-netbeans-to-show.html)

In Eclipse all the errors and warnings of project can be checked in **[Problems view](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cprbview.htm)** .